# Caffe installation issue

Tags: caffe

I am trying to install caffe. 
after I install the dependencies needed and everything looks fine, until I get to `make all -j4`, it fails! I believe this is compiler version error but I am not aware how to get over it, I tried many solutions, but not succeeding yet.
Here is the output I get:

```
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/caffe.bin
.build_release/tools/caffe.o: In function `void std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct<char*>(char*, char*, std::forward_iterator_tag) [clone .isra.161]':
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x89): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
.build_release/tools/caffe.o: In function `get_phase_from_flags(caffe::Phase)':
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x1db): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(char const*) const'
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x20c): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(char const*) const'
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x222): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(char const*) const'
.build_release/tools/caffe.o: In function `GetRequestedAction(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x2a3): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(char const*) const'
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x2db): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(char const*) const'
.build_release/tools/caffe.o:caffe.cpp:(.text+0x2f3): more undefined references to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(char const*) const' follow
.build_release/tools/caffe.o: In function `get_gpus(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*) [clone .constprop.353]':
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x9b6): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::numpunct<char> const& std::use_facet<std::__cxx11::numpunct<char> >(std::locale const&)'
.build_release/tools/caffe.o: In function `test()':
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x1983): undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x19f6): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x1aca): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x1c30): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x1cb8): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x1e1b): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x1e42): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x1e82): undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x1eb4): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
.build_release/tools/caffe.o: In function `train()':
caffe.cpp:(.text+0x28b3): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
caffe.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS5_EE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS5_S7_EERKS5_[_ZNSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS5_EE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS5_S7_EERKS5_]+0xbc): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
.build_release/tools/caffe.o: In function `boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_function_call>::error_info_injector(boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_function_call> const&)':
caffe.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_17bad_function_callEEC2ERKS3_[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_17bad_function_callEEC5ERKS3_]+0xb): undefined reference to `std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)'
.build_release/tools/caffe.o: In function `void boost::throw_exception<boost::bad_function_call>(boost::bad_function_call const&)':
caffe.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15throw_exceptionINS_17bad_function_callEEEvRKT_[_ZN5boost15throw_exceptionINS_17bad_function_callEEEvRKT_]+0x45): undefined reference to `std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)'
caffe.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15throw_exceptionINS_17bad_function_callEEEvRKT_[_ZN5boost15throw_exceptionINS_17bad_function_callEEEvRKT_]+0x9f): undefined reference to `std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)'
.build_release/tools/caffe.o: In function `std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >& boost::algorithm::iter_split<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> > >(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >)':
caffe.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9algorithm10iter_splitISt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS8_EEKS8_NS0_6detail13token_finderFINSC_10is_any_ofFIcEEEEEERT_SI_RT0_T1_[_ZN5boost9algorithm10iter_splitISt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS8_EEKS8_NS0_6detail13token_finderFINSC_10is_any_ofFIcEEEEEERT_SI_RT0_T1_]+0x963): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
.build_release/tools/caffe.o: In function `std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >& boost::algorithm::iter_split<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> > >(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >)':
caffe.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9algorithm10iter_splitISt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS8_EES8_NS0_6detail13token_finderFINSB_10is_any_ofFIcEEEEEERT_SH_RT0_T1_[_ZN5boost9algorithm10iter_splitISt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS8_EES8_NS0_6detail13token_finderFINSB_10is_any_ofFIcEEEEEERT_SH_RT0_T1_]+0x963): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace_aux(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, char)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator[](unsigned long)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so: undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(unsigned long, char, std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator[](unsigned long) const'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::length() const'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::assign(char const*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::append(unsigned long, char)'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2: undefined reference to `std::range_error::range_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_erase(unsigned long, unsigned long)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::str() const'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace_aux(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, char)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long) const'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream()@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(char const*)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::rfind(char, unsigned long) const@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::clear()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_append(char const*, unsigned long)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator+=(char const*)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find(char const*, unsigned long) const'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::reserve(unsigned long)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::resize(unsigned long, char)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find(char, unsigned long) const@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::substr(unsigned long, unsigned long) const@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_mutate(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find_last_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::erase(unsigned long, unsigned long)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::begin()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream(std::_Ios_Openmode)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::domain_error::domain_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find_first_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream()@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_sync(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::size() const'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator+=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::append(char const*, unsigned long)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*) const'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::c_str() const'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::resize(unsigned long, char)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::swap(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator>><char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::getline<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, char)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator+=(char)'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2: undefined reference to `std::length_error::length_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::substr(unsigned long, unsigned long) const'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::rfind(char, unsigned long) const'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find_first_not_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)@GLIBCXX_3.4.20'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::empty() const'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::append(char const*)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::assign(char const*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so: undefined reference to `std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf-2_2.so.22: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_stringstream(std::_Ios_Openmode)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::append(char const*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(char const*) const@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2: undefined reference to `std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so: undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct(unsigned long, char)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::append(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libleveldb.so: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length@CXXABI_1.3.8'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::swap(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2: undefined reference to `std::invalid_argument::invalid_argument(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::numpunct<char> const& std::use_facet<std::__cxx11::numpunct<char> >(std::locale const&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::assign(char const*, unsigned long)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so: undefined reference to `std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::getline<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, char)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::logic_error::logic_error(std::logic_error const&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so: undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::overflow_error::overflow_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find(char, unsigned long) const'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct(unsigned long, char)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2: undefined reference to `std::out_of_range::out_of_range(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgflags.so.2: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::data() const'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::end()'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `std::out_of_range::out_of_range(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:625: recipe for target '.build_release/tools/caffe.bin' failed
make: *** [.build_release/tools/caffe.bin] Error 1
```

I removed part of the error for the question space limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Right -- somehow, you're not getting access to the standard compiler library, **std**, and other basic packages.  We can't do much to debug without the set-up characteristics: which compiler versions are in your path, the order of dependency installation, etc.  Also, check the compiler-version lines in Makefile.config: see that the requested versions exist.

In case it helps, my list of support packages for Caffe installation is:

wget cmake git screen gcc python-pip python-devel boost boost-devel cmake numpy numpy-devel gflags gflags-devel glog glog-devel protobuf protobuf-devel hdf5 hdf5-devel lmdb lmdb-devel leveldb leveldb-devel snappy-devel opencv opencv-devel

This isn't compactly called out on the BVLC site.

Comment: `gcc --version` -->  `gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609`

the make.config doesnt contain any specifications for the gcc andI believe I have all these packages installed, is there a way to quick check if they are installed or not ?

Comment: What distribution of Caffe are you using?  BVLC and Intel Caffe don't use "make.config" -- they supply "Makefile.config.example", which you copy to "Makefile.config" and edit as needed.  They both include a variable "CUSTOM_CXX", which can be your choice of gcc.

Comment: For checking your build, try "ldd ./build/tools/caffe" -- this will give you an excruciatingly complete list of the object files linked into that executable.

Comment: I use the default the provided makefile provided by caffe, and leave the
`# CUSTOM_CXX := g++` commented. I try the ldd command you mention but it is not working mentioning `ldd: ./build/tools/caffe: No such file or directory` from inside the caffe directory, there is no folder caffe created in the build tools folder

Comment: OOPS!  My fault -- that's the path to the executable you can't build.

Comment: There is no **makefile** in the BVLC Caffe GitHub repo.  **Makefile** is the application; you shouldn't edit that at all.  **Makefile.config.example** is what you copy and edit.  As for checking versions ... let me look for some tea-stained notes ...

Comment: I mean I copied the make.config.example into my own makefile.config as stated in the steps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138750/discussion-between-kasparov92-and-prune).